# Use CoreData in MonoTouch?

Tags: core-data, xamarin.ios

I have seen that there are so wonderful ways in Xcode to design your CoreData models - is there a way to make use of this and CoreData in general in MonoTouch 5?
Any tutorials or examples?

Comment: mmm, just curious what are you trying to achieve using CoreData??

Comment: Get rid of direct usage of SQL commands. I am now using SQlite.net instead, but it is not as sophisticated as Core Data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe is not the direct answer to your question but might be what you `are looking for:`

- [Sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) is an open source, minimal library to allow .NET and Mono applications to store data in SQLite 3 databases. <- `the one you are using but for future reference`
- [Vici CoolStorage](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/coolstorage/home) is a fully typed Object Relational Mapping library for .NET 3.5, Windows Phone, **MonoTouch** and Mono for Android
- [Catnap](https://github.com/timscott/catnap) is a basic lightweight ORM for .NET. It uses the ADO.NET API. The project includes an adapter for Sqlite, and it is tested with System.Data.Sqlite and Mono.Data.Sqlite.
- [MonoTouch.SQLite](https://github.com/jstedfast/MonoTouch.SQLite) An abstract UITableViewController to make displaying data from an SQLite table simpler.
- [Entify](http://code.google.com/p/entify/) is entity framework for desktop and mobile applications. It aims to be stable and easy-to-use library that is effortless to deploy with any application. It has visual designer which allows developer to define application data model easily and quickly.

  - Just a side note on `entify`, it has not been updated since `Apr 11, 2010` so idk if it still works

The only thing I could find about `MonoTouch` and `CoreData` was [this blog post](http://www.sgmunn.com/2010/10/coredata_in_monotouch/).

Hope this helps.

Alex

Comment: Just an update:  As of March '13, Vici seems to be no longer maintained, the documentation is inaccurate, and their forums and blog are gone.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the documentation](http://api.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=N:MonoMac.CoreData) for CoreData in Mono.

[This blog post](http://sgmunn.com/blog/2010/10/coredata-in-monotouch/) is almost two years old, but the only example I could find of using CoreData in Mono.

Most relevant to your question, however, [this bug/request](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1940) is for integrating Xcode's tools into Mono.  It doesn't seem to even be under development yet.

**Edit:**
You can also use `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/momc <source xcdatamodel> <absolute path to target>` to generate the `.momd`.  I'm still working on getting it integrated better - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241014/generate-classes-from-coredata-model).