# .NET C# version of Core Data

Tags: c#, .net, core-data

Is there a .NET C# version of the OS X/iOS CoreData? I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2997154/703161), but it needs to be for C# .NET.

Comment: What is it exactly you are looking to do.. are you looking at wanting to use Entity Framework..?

Comment: I haven't used CoreData but you could implement a lot of the functionality with a bit of clever thinking and reflection on top of an EF Data Store. From the list of features on the Wikipedia page, EF5 should do 90% of what you want. You should also look into the repository pattern which will probably take you the rest of the way

Comment: Very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743339/use-coredata-in-monotouch

Comment: The goal is to find something that easy to implement and more robust then xml for storing User data on a client application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this question, [Nhiberate](https://nhibernate.info/) was what we ended up going with as an ORM. Currently, for most projects, we are using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

**Update 2022:**

The [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) has evolved quite a bit since this question was asked and could certainly fill the role that I was looking for at the time of question.

Answer (score 4):

you can try [mono](http://xamarin.com/monotouch), a framework for creating apps for iOS

Comment: +1 Funny, I've always thought of mono as simply a linux port of the CLR which happens to support iOS (being linux based). I probably wouldn't have thought to recommend it specifically for iOS development

Comment: @Styxxy Of course you're right - clearly more tired than I thought

Comment: Mono is not the right solution for this. It is going to be a native .NET client

Comment: @DogEatDog are you looking for an ORM framework as NHibernate for persistence purposes?

Comment: I'm looking for something that handles the leg work of writing the SQL queries and such. Much like how CoreData works for iOS, or how Django handles it for it's webapps in python.

Comment: So i suggest you to try NHibernate, it's a framework for .NET that allows you to create an OO domain model from a relational database, in this way you don't have to write any SQL query but you use only the objects. Cheers